# Identifying poker card value and suit using iOS live-capture

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm working on a hobby project that requires me to be able to use a front facing camera to effectively scan a poker card, identifying the value and suit, using live-capture. Think dealing cards to players, and hovering the card over the camera. The card would be very close up (as to not show the value to other players), so only a portion of the card might be seen. Typically, the top left or bottom right of most playing cards has all the info you'd need, Value over Suit.

I've tried CreateML, turi-create OSOD, object detection with annotated localization coordinates, etc. But I'm never really getting the accuracy I'm hoping for. Leaving me to think that this might be a little too much for ML, at least for live-capture. I've also tried scanning an entire deck, using the full card face, as well as using only the corner.

Any thoughts, tips, ideas, recommendations, etc would be extremely appreciated.